# Properties of Linear subspace of function space

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The situation is the following: Suppose $X$ is a compact topological space. Let $A\subset  C(X)$ be a linear subpace of the space of continuous functions on $X$. Assume that we know that for $x,y\in X$, $x\neq y$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $f\in A$ with $f(x)=a$ and $f(y)=b$. Furthermore, assume that: if $g\in A$, then $g^3,g^4,g^5,\ldots\in A$.

I want to prove that $g^2\in A$ for all $g\in A$. Maybe one can use that we approximate the function $x^2$ by polynomials with powers only of the form $4m$ for $m\geq1$. Does one have an idea to come to the conclusion?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true, unfortunately. Let $X=[a,b]$ with either $a>0$ or $b<0$ and let
$$A:=\{f\in C(X)\,|\,f(x)=a_1x+\sum_{j=3}^na_jx^j\ \text{for some}\ a_j\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$
Then $A$ is clearly a subspace of $C(X)$, and obviously $f\in A$ implies $f^3,f^4,f^5,\ldots\in A$. Now let $f(x)=x$; $f\in A$ but $f^2\notin A$. Hence to verify this is a counterexample we need only show that given $y,z\in[a,b]$, $y\neq z$ and $a_0,b_0\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists $f\in A$ with $f(y)=a_0$ and $f(z)=b_0$. We can do this using a modified Lagrange polynomial; letting
$$f(x)=\left(\frac{x-z}{a_0^2(y-z)}+\frac{x-y}{b_0^2(z-y)}\right)x^3$$
gives us such a function.

Comment: Hence the implication is not true?!

Comment: if we add that $f\in A$ implies $f^3,f^4,\ldots$ **for all $f\in A$**, does this change the claim?

Comment: The implication is not true. We already have $f^3,f^4,\ldots\in A$ for all $f\in A$. If $f\in A$, $f(x)=xp(x)$ for some polynomial $p$, so $f^n(x)=x^np^n(x)$ which is a polynomial where the lowest term is of order no less than $n$.

Comment: What has to be edit such that the statement is wel true?

Comment: Any additional information I can think of would be a little too strong in that it would make most of your current conditions redundant. For instance, if $A$ contains a nonzero constant function then $A$ will be closed under squares if and only if it is closed under cubes, if and only if it closed under pointwise multiplication. All the other conditions become redundant.